# Reapeat RDLC Report :each object in Page

Tags: .net, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have made my rdlc report with texboxs and elements and i want to have the same report template with each object in page

do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Probleme , I created a Table with one column and inside this one column i've insert my template .

I used also the group condition on the table column.